# VueJs - Focus to element in an imported component

Tags: vue.js

I'm new to VueJs so trying to get to grips with how everything works and comes to together. Basically I have two vue files. I'm importing one of the files into the other.

In the main file I'd like to focus to an input element in the imported component but I can't seem to work out how to do this?

So in my main file I've imported the component and have this code:

In the SelfScan.vue file I have a basic input element. I have some focus code within this file which works fine.

So I was hoping to do something similar like this:

this.$refs.selfscan.barcode.focus();

However "selfscan" is undefined.

Please can you help me to understand what I'm doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code. It's impossible for anyone to know what's wrong in your code without seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you set focus in any element in Vue.js, you need to use [ref attribute](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Accessing-Child-Component-Instances-amp-Child-Elements). Is correct.

But the property this.$refs is available only local component scope. In other words, if you need to set focus by other component, you need a global event. There is other ways you do this, but the global event is more simple.

The code will be that way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="focusChildInput">Focus to Input</button>
    <child />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import child from './child.vue';

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: { child },
  methods: {
    focusChildInput() {
      this.$root.$emit('focusChildInput');
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ref="childInput" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'child',
  mounted() {
    this.$root.$on('focusChildInput', () => this.$refs.childInput.focus());
  },
};
</script>
```